# Mod Rewrite link, and disable original

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a working mod-rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^notifications$ /notifications.php [L]
```

However, I've seen on some sites, their links seems to be all like website.com/login website.com/notifications website.com/profile

I think I have achieved the same results with my mod-rewrite. But how can I prevent users from entering my /notifications.php page like how some other website does?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add another rule that looks for a direct request for the `php` file and redirect it to the non `php` URL:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /notifications\.php
RewriteRule ^ /notifications [L,R=301]
```